# c++ store on heap save on stack

Tags: c++, heap-memory, stack-memory

I have a code which dynamically allocates a 2D array, uses it for some computation, then puts it onto a variable named result on stack and deallocates the 2D array. I was wondering why this works and is it a good programming practice to do it this way rather than having a global 2D array that can be deallocated later.

```
{

        int *matrix = new int[5];

        for(row = 0; row<array_size+1;row++)
        {
            subSolution[row] = new (nothrow) int[request+1];
            if(subSolution[row] == NULL)
               return -1;
        }
        //do some stuff

        result = subSolution[1][request];

        for(row = 0; row<array_size+1; row++ )
            delete [] subSolution[row];

        delete [] subSolution;

        return result;

}
```

Thanks

Comment: I would strongly recommend you to show some code of what you are doing as you are likely to get downvotes, because what you say is not most probably possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no magic )) You made a **copy** of one element of the array. Now you can modify array or even delete it... your **copy** will be permanent. But if you'd save a **pointer** to one element of the array, and then delete an array, you'll have a trouble:

```
int * pElement = & matrix[ i ][ j ];
deleteMatrix();
int x = *pElement; // bad
```

Comment: Why I thought this was a bad programming practice is that it could cause potential crashes. Suppose instead of = in result above, I use memcpy. So, potentially I could overwrite parts of the function stack. I'm not sure if at runtime, it will crash just after executing memcpy. Maybe afterwards when you try to access something else on the stack ?

Comment: Aaaa... Mmmmmm... There are two  variants: (1) my english is very poor so I can understand nothing in your comment (2) your comment have no sense.... Can you rephrase a question ?

Answer (score 0):

The information you've given us is:

- You have a dynamically allocated 2D array, presumably called matrix, which you say you free before returning from the function.
- You have code that says `int result = matrix[i][j]` which, as you say, is stored on the stack.

You're not returning the array.  You're returning the int found at `[i][j]` of the array, so this is perfectly good, valid code.

If you had

```
int** result = matrix;
delete matrix;
// ...
int i = result[5][3];
```

This would cause undefined behavior.  Since the memory has been freed by your function, there could be anything in its place.  If nothing has stomped on the memory, it could look perfect, or it could be completely corrupted.